# Use a for_each to attach varying number of disks to varying number of VM's

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

TF version: 0.13.4

Provider version: 2.40.0

I'm not sure on the best/most efficient way to do this, but what I'm trying to achieve is to attach 2 disks (for now) to each VM, but I need to be able to configure each VM and disk as per requirements. I may need to vary the number of disks and VM's in the future. I'm trying to get the for_each to loop over the size and based on how many values are in there, create that amount of disks so that I can have multiple disks with different sizes.

Is there a way to do this without having to create multiple managed disk resources manually?

My current code creates varying number of VM's but only attaches one disk per VM. The variables that the for_each iterates over are set in a tfvars file per environment:

```
desktop_servers = {
  "Server_1" = {
    name = 1,
    zone = 1,
    lun  = 1,
    size = 32
  }
  "Server_2" = {
    name = 2,
    zone = 2,
    lun  = 2,
    size = 32
  }

  "Server_3" = {
    name = 3,
    zone = 3,
    lun  = 3,
    size = 32
  }
}

etl_servers = {
  "Server_1" = {
    name = 1,
    zone = 1,
    lun  = 1,
    size = 32
  }
  "Server_2" = {
    name = 2,
    zone = 2,
    lun  = 2,
    size = 32
  }
}
```

virtual machine resource within the module.tf

```
# Azure Virtual Machine
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine" {
  for_each                         = var.servers
  name                             = "vm-${var.environment}-${var.vm_identifier}${each.value.name}"
  location                         = var.location
  resource_group_name              = var.resource_group
  zone                             = each.value.zone
  size                             = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids            = [azurerm_network_interface.network_interface[each.key].id]
  computer_name                    = "${var.vm_identifier}${each.value.name}"
  admin_username                   = xxxx
  admin_password                   = xxxx
  provision_vm_agent               = "true"
  source_image_id                  = data.azurerm_shared_image.dwp_shared_image.id


  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = data.azurerm_storage_account.dwp_diag_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint
  }

  os_disk {
    name                      = "vm-${var.environment}-${var.directorate}-${var.business_unit}-${var.vm_identifier}-os${each.value.name}"
    caching                   = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type      = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_network_interface.network_interface]
}
```

managed disk resource within module.tf :

```
# #Managed disks per vm
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "managed_disk" {
  for_each               = var.servers
  name                   = "disk-${var.environment}-${var.vm_identifier}${each.value.name}"
  location               = var.location
  resource_group_name    = var.resource_group
  storage_account_type   = "Premium_LRS"
  create_option          = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb           = each.value.size
  zones                  = [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine[each.key].zone]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "disk_attachment" {
  for_each           = var.servers
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.managed_disk[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine[each.key].id
  lun                = each.value.lun
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

variable.tf within the module:

```
variable "servers" {
  description = "Variable for defining each instance"
}
```

Example of a module for the ETL servers in the main.tf. :

```
module "etl_vm" {
  source                       = "../modules/compute/windows_vm"
  location                     = var.location
  resource_group               = azurerm_resource_group.rg_sbox_etl.name
  directorate                  = var.directorate
  business_unit                = var.business_unit
  environment                  = var.environment
  network_rg_identifier        = var.network_rg_identifier
  subnet_name                  = "sub-${var.environment}-${var.directorate}-${var.business_unit}-be01"
  diag_storage_account_name    = var.diag_storage_account_name
  log_analytics_workspace_name = var.log_analytics_workspace_name
  backup_policy_name           = var.backup_policy_name
  vm_identifier                = "${var.vm_identifier}${var.instance_number}-etl"
  servers                      = var.etl_servers
  vm_size                      = var.etl_vm_size
  enable_management_locks      = true
  image_name                   = "WIN2016-CISL2"
  gallery_subscription_id      = var.sub_id
  gallery_resourcegroup        = var.rg_gallery
  gallery_name                 = "SBOXGallery"
```

Comment: How does `var.servers` relate to `etl_servers` and `desktop_servers`? Is it a joint map of these two variables?

Comment: I have updated my code to show how they link together. `var.servers' is an input variable defined in the module. 'etl_servers' are defined in the tfvars files and called within the module.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks - I can see how this will solve the issue and from the plan I ran, it looks good. I'm having issue with a nested provider as a result of adding the for_each to the calling module, but thats a separate issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the module to achieve it. But it's a little complex. The idea is that you use the module to configure the VM, in each VM, you can configure different data disks and attach them to the VM. Use the variable to input different VM number of the configuration. Here is an example:

main.tf

```
variable "rg_name" {
    type = string
}

variable "vms" {
    type = map(object({
        size = string
        admin_user = string
        admin_password = string
        disks = list(number)
    }))
}

variable "location" {}

module "vms" {
    for_each = var.vms
    
    source = "./modules/vm"
    resource_group_name = var.rg_name
    vm_name = each.key
    vm = each.value
    disks = each.value["disks"]
    location = var.location
}
```

terraform.tfvar

```
rg_name = "charlesVMs"
location = "East US"
vms ={
  azurevm1 = {
    
    size = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    admin_user = "azureuser"
    admin_password = "azureuser@2021"
    disks = [30, 30]
  }
}
```

./modules/vm/main.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {}

variable "vm" {}

variable "disks" {}

variable "location" {}

variable "vm_name" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    name  = var.resource_group_name
    location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name              = var.vm_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = var.vm["size"]

  disable_password_authentication = false
  admin_username      = var.vm["admin_user"]
  admin_password      = var.vm["admin_password"]
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id
  ]

  # admin_ssh_key {
  #   username   = "adminuser"
  #   public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  # }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "example" {
  count       = length(var.vm["disks"])
  name        = "datadisk-${count.index}"
  location    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb    = element(var.vm["disks"], count.index)
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "example" {
  count              = length(var.vm["disks"])
  managed_disk_id    = element(azurerm_managed_disk.example.*.id, count.index)
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  lun                = count.index
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

You only need to give the varying number of VM's configuration and the varying number of disks with sizes for the `vms` variable.